# ROS Controller_manager

Tags: ros

I installed the ROS controller_manager using "sudo apt get ros-kinetic-ros-controller-manager"

After installation of the package,i created my own package with my own config and launch file. Next when i do a catkin_make, i received the following error:

i have tried to do a sudo apt update before installing the package.

CMake Error at /home/innosparks/catkin_ws/devel/share/controller_manager/cmake/controller_managerConfig.cmake:113 (message):
  Project 'controller_manager' specifies
  '/home/innosparks/catkin_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager/include' as
  an include dir, which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute
  directory nor in
  '/home/innosparks/catkin_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager//home/innosparks/catkin_ws/src/ros_control/controller_manager/include'.
  Check the issue tracker
  'https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues' and consider creating
  a ticket if the problem has not been reported yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  myrobot_control/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/innosparks/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/innosparks/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:3524: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Answer (score 1):

Update the keys for the corresponding Ros-vesion from ros website
and then run..

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<version>-controller-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package with:

**sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-controller-manager**

I propose to try out the tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control/Tutorials